# How to Get URI in Lumen 5.4

Tags: php, lumen

How to get the URI of named routes in Lumen 5.4?

I saw the route helper method but the 3rd parameter is for secure connection.

Here is my route:

```
$app->get('/users/{id}', [
                'as'    => 'users.show',
                'uses'  => 'UserController@show'
            ]
        ));.

// Here is how I call my route
route('users.show', ['id' => 1]);
```

Comment: Share your code ?

Comment: @Rishi What code? I'm using the route helper method but can't find a way to get the relative URI. The route helper method always returns absolute URL.

Comment: If you don't mind you can also share your `route` that how did you make that

Comment: I updated my question.

Answer (score 2):

I've dealt with the same problem by adding my own helper function, I guess lumen doesn't support relative routes.

```
public static function relativeRoute($routeName){
        if (Cache::has($routeName . 'Route')){ //Cache to avoid looping the routes every time
            return Cache::get($routeName . 'Route');
        }
        $routes = app()->getRoutes();
        $filteredRoutes = array_filter($routes,function($route) use ($routeName) {
            return isset($route['action']['as']) && strcmp($route['action']['as'], $routeName) == 0;
        });
        $filteredRoutes = array_values($filteredRoutes);
        $route = count($filteredRoutes) != 1 ? null : $filteredRoutes[0]['uri'];//there should only be one route with that name
        Cache::put($routeName . 'Route' , $route , 60);
        return $route;
    }
```